# How can I tell if I am no longer using beta?

Tags: 12.04, beta

Is there a way to tell if I am still using beta after upgrading? I've been constantly upgrading my beta and I am, as far as I know, completely up to date. But, I can't really tell if I am up to date in terms of beta or 12.04 as a whole.

Is there a command I can run to check?

Comment: Try with `update-manager -d` and find out if you see an Upgrade button. Or run System Monitor and check out the _System_ tab and read the text under _Ubuntu_.

Comment: `update-manager -d` did not have the upgrade button like it did whenever I upgraded from 11.10 to beta. And, the System tab reads "Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit". I'm assuming that this means that I am out of beta?

If that's the case, go ahead and make your comment into an answer that way you get the reputation you deserve for it.

On another note, how exactly did I leave beta and go into release? Did updating replace all beta-related packages with release packages?

Comment: Relax and have fun. BTW: which Kernel do you have installed? `uname -a` to find out.

Comment: I have 3.2.0.24 generic

Comment: Then you have the LTS version. Great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with update-manager -d and find out if you see an Upgrade button. Or run System Monitor and check out the System tab and read the text under Ubuntu. 
If there shows **Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit** you are out of beta.

Enjoy the new LTS release and have fun with Ubuntu ;)